# What is the orange Highlight that sometimes appears

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I refresh a page, I get an orange highlight over a comment or an answer like so- [image]

what does this mean?

Comment: Say if you ask a question, then there is an answer to your question, it is notified in your inbox, It says something like: There was an answer on your question. You click that, it will take you to the page where your question is and will automatically scroll down to the question and highlight it orange to show the specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Orange means: *this is what you asked for.*

Sites in the StackExchange network put several blocks of information (question + multiple answers, comments) on one page. All blocks have to be linked to in a user-friendly way. For example, when you get a notification of a comment, the notification links to that comment. When you see a new answer on the active tab of the front page, you want to be linked to that answer.

From a UX point of view, this is a horror: you have to let the browser scroll down to the block the user asked for. However, often, after you scroll, the page changes with images that get loaded and so. Therefore, you have to scroll intelligently, and in addition to that, it's a good idea to add some other mark to that 'special' item on the page. StackExchange does that, or at least on this site, by highlighting the item and fading the background color out to not make it a bad read.

Also, this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZN5PoW7_kdA

Comment: Actually modern browsers are clever enough to wait for things to load before jumping. But yeah, they occasionally goof up so it's a useful feature.

Comment: @Manishearth mobile browsers don't (or at least mine doesn't)

Comment: That's not what I meant by a "modern browser". Mine does -- usually -- but fails spectacularly on large pages.